# firebase hosting "unable to load domains"

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-console

I'm using firebase hosting, but it worked fine before, and I didn't make any changes in the meantime, but suddenly the hosting site couldn't be accessed.
I don't use a custom domain, and I use the hosting domain provided by firebase, so it doesn't seem like a domain problem, but I can't connect and I don't know what the problem is.

When I click the site, the site cannot be connected and the firebase screen says "unable to load domains"

[image: 1]

Comment: I recommend disabling all browser extensions and trying again. If that doesn't fix it, it is unlikely a problem we can help with and I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: There is a problem with firebase itself. I got this message "Firebase Hosting is aware of some reports of connection issues in the APAC and EMEA regions. We are currently investigating." Hope firebase resolves it soon.

Comment: i also get this when i've restored the deleted project under 30 days. Have people found the ways to fix? i deploy and can't get it up online, showing error 404.